# limit array member dependent on different array and count

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I created a site by laravel and I want to show categories and relevant products names.

i have tow array and like this

```php
$category  = [
    '1' => 'cat1',
    '2' => 'cat2'
];

$product = [
    '0' => array(
     'name' => 'product1',
     'category_id' => '2'
),
    '1' => array(
     'name' => 'product2',
     'category_id' => '2'
),
    '2' => array(
     'name' => 'product3',
     'category_id' => '2'
),
    '3' => array(
     'name' => 'product4',
     'category_id' => '1'
),
    '4' => array(
     'name' => 'product5',
     'category_id' => '1'
),
    '5' => array(
     'name' => 'product6',
     'category_id' => '2'
),
    '6' => array(
     'name' => 'product7',
     'category_id' => '2'

];
```

and i can showing them like this

```html
<h3>cat1</h3>
<p>product4</p>
<p>product5</p> 
<hr>
<hr> 
<h3>cat2</h3>
<p>product1</p>
<p>product2</p>
<p>product3</p>
<p>product6</p> 
<p>product7</p>
```

by this code

```php
// controller


public function someMethod(){
    $category  = [
        '1' => 'cat1',
        '2' => 'cat2'
    ];

    $product = [
        '0' => array(
         'name' => 'product1',
         'category_id' => '2'
    ),
        '1' => array(
         'name' => 'product2',
         'category_id' => '2'
    ),
        '2' => array(
         'name' => 'product3',
         'category_id' => '2'
    ),
        '3' => array(
         'name' => 'product4',
         'category_id' => '1'
    ),
        '4' => array(
         'name' => 'product5',
         'category_id' => '1'
    ),
        '5' => array(
         'name' => 'product6',
         'category_id' => '2'
    )]; 

    $category_collection = collect($product)->groupBy('category_id')->toArray();

    return view('your_blade_name',compact('category_collection','category'));


// view


@foreach($category_collection as $category_id => $data)
    <h3>{{ $category[$category_id] }}</h3>
    @foreach($data as $current_data)
        <p>{{ $current_data['name'] }}</p>
    @endforeach
<hr>
<hr> 
@endforeach
}
```

i can't limit this product. and my code showing all products with parent category in the section.

i want limit them so that the product count never exceeds 4 be.

if you can write laravel code but if you cant just write php code

Comment: What did you do for achieving your goal?

Comment: i just create a controller and view and inserting the codes

Comment: Yeap, [I know how you did that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59064525/showing-array-member-dependent-the-name-of-difference-array/59064656#59064656).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `@break` with some condition. This also can helpful https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

```
@foreach($category_collection as $category_id => $data)
    <h3>{{ $category[$category_id] }}</h3>
    @foreach($data as $current_data)
        @if($loop->iteration > 5) // or other logic
            @break
        @endif
        <p>{{ $current_data['name'] }}</p>
    @endforeach
    <hr>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Works.

```
foreach($category as $ck => $catval){
    foreach($product as $val){   
      if($val['category_id'] == $ck){
        $array[$catval][] =  $val;
      }
    }
  }
  foreach($array as $k => $value){
    echo '<h3>'.$k.'</h3>';
    if(count($value) > 0){
      foreach($value as $productval){ 
        echo '<p>'.$productval['name'].'</p>';
      }
    }
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cat1
product4

product5

cat2
product1

product2

product3

product6

product7
```

Comment: The output is not limited. Also, this is duplicated answer.